# How to populate user related data in IdentityServer4 on email confirmation

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have created a project scaffolded by Visual Studio 2019 using Angular and MVC Rest API using C# and .NET Core with Entity Framework.

I selected to use IdentityServer4 to register and confirm user emails. With this you also get password reset functionality, a login screen etc... I have configured SendGrid to send emails and have also hooked into Facebook as a authentication provider.

I wish to create user specific data after a user confirms their account on clicking the confirm link that was emailed to them. The user specific data is in the form of other tables and needs to be populated on confirmation.

I am at the point thinking that I have to write the code I have gotten for free (IdentityServer4) to get what I want done.

My question is how do I hook into the confirmation of the email\user to populate the tables with the users individual data? Is there an event\hook or interface that I should be providing.

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: So this is step 2 of the registration? The user has to complete the data after confirming the email?

Comment: I suppose so. But it's the system completing the data after confirming email not the user.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Does the user have to enter it or are you retrieving information from facebook? And why wait until the email is confirmed? Why itsn't this part of the registration step?

Comment: Not from facebook. If I create prior to registration - i still need another hook, wouldn't I? Also if the registration does not occur I need to delete the users data. So wouldn't it introduce more hooks required?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Identity Core for User storage? If yes, then mention it in the question if not then what do you mean by "I selected to use IdentityServer4 to register and confirm user emails"? @DavidGrayWright

Comment: I thought they were the same thing? Am I incorrect? Like I said I scaffolded the project using Visual Studio 2019 - what comes with it? I’ll investigate and update question then.

Comment: You can use identity server (a OpenID/OAuth STS) in "standalone" mode, where you provide to it the users, or you can use it together with ASP.NET Identity. So it looks like you chose the latter.